# Is Theranos the first laboratory that publishes their prices and lab proficiency-testing scores on their website?

Tags: medical-science, theranos

Theranos writes in [Theranos Facts](https://www.theranos.com/news/posts/custom/theranos-facts):

> To our knowledge, we are the first laboratory to publish our prices, lab proficiency-testing scores, customer satisfaction scores, guest visit times, and more on our website.

Is it true that Theranos is the first laboratory that does this, when we focus on laboratories and exclude resellers?

Comment: Worth noting that, since this question was asked/answered, [Theranos has closed its blood-testing labs](https://techcrunch.com/2017/01/17/theranos-last-lab-inspection-test-fail/).  Theranos may've been the first lab that did it, but they don't appear to anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theranos launched their first location in 2013 ([ref here](https://www.theranos.com/news), second article from the bottom).  They seem to be unique in providing lab proficiency-testing results.  Many other labs however who have been around longer have the same business model.  Here are just a few.

[Any Lab Test Now](https://www.anylabtestnow.com/) has been providing direct access (no doctor order necessary) walk-in lab tests since 1992 according to [this page](https://www.anylabtestnow.com/about-us/), and has been licensing franchisees since 2007.  They [publish their prices (click any test for the price)](https://www.anylabtestnow.com/test-finder/test-all-lab/) on their site along with [testimonials](https://www.anylabtestnow.com/testimonials/).  They have a location finder (on main page) which display hours of operation for each location.

[HealthLabs](https://www.healthlabs.com/) has been providing direct access testing, and publishes their prices (click on a category on the home page to get started), [posts testimonials](https://www.healthlabs.com/patient-testimon), and has a [location finder](https://www.healthlabs.com/find-a-lab) with hours.  They appear to be in business since 2002.

Another direct access provider, [True Health Labs](http://www.truehealthlabs.com/) has been around for over five years, lists a price and draw location once you have [selected your tests](http://www.truehealthlabs.com/Lab-Tests-s/1820.htm), and posts [customer reviews](http://www.truehealthlabs.com/Raving-Reviews-s/1914.htm).

Comment: Also, [Accesa Labs](https://www.accesalabs.com) has supposedly tested over 30,000 customers.

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses whether the other mentioned labs published their prices before Theranos.   Sure, other labs might do it, but who was first?